# Python: Assign selected faces to vertex group

Tags: python, vertex-groups

I have a script that selects some random faces and splits them. I would like to add the selection to a vertex group. I can't get my script to assign the selection to a vertex group. Thank you for the help.

```
            sub2 = 0
            bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')
            bpy.ops.mesh.select_random(percent=55, seed=10, action='DESELECT')
            bpy.ops.mesh.split()    
            group = context.object.vertex_groups.new()
            group.name = ("Island" + str(sub2))
            #group.add(bpy.data.objects.data.verts, 1.0, 'ADD')
            bpy.ops.object.vertex_group_assign()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have missing "bpy" on line 4, so it should be:

```
group = bpy.context.object.vertex_groups.new()
```

Don't forget to import bpy:

```
import bpy
```

### Whole script:

```
import bpy
sub2 = 0
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')
bpy.ops.mesh.select_random(percent=55, seed=10, action='DESELECT')
bpy.ops.mesh.split()    
group = bpy.context.object.vertex_groups.new()
group.name = ("Island" + str(sub2))
#group.add(bpy.data.objects.data.verts, 1.0, 'ADD')
bpy.ops.object.vertex_group_assign()
```

Comment: Oh man, something so simple. It was throwing me off because it would still create the group without the bpy if front of context. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Use Window -> Toggle System Console to see the actual error messages and the line number where your script fails. In this case, you would get "context is incorrect" error.